# Django: Perform case-insensitive lookups by default

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-orm

I need to perform case-insensitive queries on `username` by default
when using the Django Auth framework.

I tried fixing the issue by writing a custom subclass of `Queryset`
and overriding the `_filter_or_exclude` method and then using that
subclass in a custom manager for the User model-

```
from django.db.models import Manager
from django.db.models.query import QuerySet
from django.contrib.auth.models import UserManager

class MyQuerySet(QuerySet):
    def _filter_or_exclude(self, negate, *args, **kwargs):
        if 'username' in kwargs:
            kwargs['username__iexact'] = kwargs['username']
            del kwargs['username']
        return super(MyQuerySet, self)._filter_or_exclude(negate, *args, **kwargs)

class MyUserManager(UserManager):
    def get_query_set(self):
        return MyQuerySet(self.model)

User.objects = MyUserManager()
```

But this approach didn't work and I am getting an weird error when I
try doing `User.objects.get(username='Foo')`.

Any help would be appreciated.

**Update**: I am including the exact error that I am getting.

```
/usr/lib/python2.5/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py in get(self, *args, **kwargs)
    295         keyword arguments.
    296         """
--> 297         clone = self.filter(*args, **kwargs)
    298         num = len(clone)
    299         if num == 1:

/usr/lib/python2.5/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py in filter(self, *args, **kwargs)
    481         set.
    482         """
--> 483         return self._filter_or_exclude(False, *args, **kwargs)
    484 
    485     def exclude(self, *args, **kwargs):

/home/ghoseb/src/git/ocricket.git/ocricket/user/models.py in _filter_or_exclude(self, negate, *args, **kwargs)
     38             kwargs['username__iexact'] = kwargs['username']
     39             del kwargs['username']
---> 40         return super(MyQuerySet, self)._filter_or_exclude(negate, *args, **kwargs)
     41 
     42 class MyUserManager(UserManager):

/usr/lib/python2.5/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py in _filter_or_exclude(self, negate, *args, **kwargs)
    499             clone.query.add_q(~Q(*args, **kwargs))
    500         else:
--> 501             clone.query.add_q(Q(*args, **kwargs))
    502         return clone
    503 

/usr/lib/python2.5/django/db/models/sql/query.py in add_q(self, q_object, used_aliases)

/usr/lib/python2.5/django/db/models/sql/query.py in add_filter(self, filter_expr, connector, negate, trim, can_reuse, process_extras)

/usr/lib/python2.5/django/db/models/sql/query.py in get_meta(self)

<type 'exceptions.AttributeError'>: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '_meta'
```

**Update**: By the way, I just wanted to mention that when I copy the logic inside my `_filter_or_exclude` method into the actual `QuerySet` class, it works flawlessly.

Comment: Strange error.  Can you verify that you get this error on this exact code?  There are no additional methods on QuerySet or Manager overridden, and no additional intervening subclasses in the inheritance hierarchy, no additional mixins?

Comment: I suspect the problem may lie in monkeypatching User.objects?  But I haven't done enough experimentation to verify that.

Comment: I can confirm that. But it'd be great if someone could verify it.

Comment: I was right; the process of adding a manager to a class is more complex than just attribute assignment, it involves calling add_to_class -- it's all handled in the ModelBase metaclass (see db/base.py).  So your manager is never properly initialized.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13190758/django-case-insensitive-matching-of-username-from-auth-user/18731796#18731796

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Managers can't be added to classes with simple attribute assignment (`User.objects = MyManager()`).  Look at the ModelBase metaclass (db/models/base.py) to see what all is done for you behind the scenes when you subclass Model.

You should be able to make it work with `User.add_to_class('objects', MyManager())`.  Alternatively, you could make a [proxy subclass](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#proxy-models) of User and add the manager there.

Comment: I'm not sure that an abstract subclass of a concrete class is allowed or makes sense, but a proxy model would work well in this situation.

Comment: @rz Proxy models didn't exist when this answer was written :-) I'll update it.

Comment: cool!  i guess i should've made use of my newly acquired edit superpowers and just done that for you. By the way, Carl, aside of the way he was adding the manager, is this approach to obtaining a case-sensitive store with case-insensitive lookups sensible?

Comment: @rz I don't think it's insane... it's a little bit magical for my taste, I'd prefer to use a Manager that just added an additional lookup_user or some such method that performed the case-insensitive lookup, and then just use that new method in my code. Hard to say for sure without knowing more of the requirements/constraints.

Answer (score 5):

You don't want to mess with internal features of Django classes.  That way lies trouble with every upgrade in the future.

If you want to change the way people authenticate, write a custom authentication backend.

Here are two recipes.

http://www.davidcramer.net/code/224/logging-in-with-email-addresses-in-django.html

http://www.djangosnippets.org/snippets/577/

Both of these us email instead of username.  It's not hard to use case-insensitive query instead of an email query.

Comment: Well, I am well aware of custom auth backends but I don't need this for (only) auth, but for other things, like usernames used in URLs, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a recipe for the auth use case:
[Django : Case insensitive matching of username from auth user?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13190758/django-case-insensitive-matching-of-username-from-auth-user/18731796#18731796)
You're probably best off using separate solutions for each of your use cases.