# How to make Django rest_framework Session Authentication case insensitive?

Tags: python, django, authentication, django-rest-framework, case-insensitive

I'm using Django rest framework basic authentication with the following code:

```
class MyBasicAuthentication(BasicAuthentication):

    def authenticate_header(self, request):
        return 'xBasic realm="%s"' % self.www_authenticate_realm


class AuthView(APIView):
    authentication_classes = (MyBasicAuthentication,)
    serializer_class = UserSerializer

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        user = authenticate(username=request.user.username, password=request.user.password)
        login(request, user)

        response = get_user_basic_info(request.user)

        return Response(response)
```

It is working fine, but I need to make this authentication case insensitive for the username. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

How about just choosing all upper or all lower case characters for the username stored in the database. IE for all uppercase:

```
user = authenticate(username=str(request.user.username).upper(), password=request.user.password)
```

This way the input can be mixed case but the output in standardized.

Comment: a better way to do what you propose with be to do authenticate(username_iexact=request.user.username),password=request.user.password) but the problem here is that django rest_framework authentication (BasicAuthentication.www_authenticate_realm) takes place before this line which authenticates the user with Django's regular Auth

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way of doing this is standardizing the way you store the usernames (in upper or lower case as @Upsampled answered) which would mean that the authentication that occurs first would not have a problem. If you want to change all existing users to a particular case I would recommend this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/33456271