# Override Django User Manager to only return active users in queries

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-queryset

Need a way for calls to `User.objects.filter/get` to only return User objects with `is_active` set to True.

I tried to define a custom Manager and monkey patch it onto the User model, like this:

```
class CustomUserManager(UserManager):

    def get_query_set(self):
        return super(CustomUserManager, self).get_query_set().
          filter(is_active=True)

User.objects = CustomUserManager()
User.objects_all = UserManager()
```

But, when I try to make a call to User.objects.get(), I get:
`AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '_meta'`

Before I go any further, I'd want to say that I know that monkey patching like this is very bad form in terms of maintainability -- this will be marked to be revisited later, but right now we need a quick solution.

Here's the full stack trace, if anyone wants that as well:

```
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Users/zarathustra/Virtual_Envs/fierce-spring-7383/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py", line 131, in get
    return self.get_query_set().get(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/zarathustra/Virtual_Envs/fierce-spring-7383/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 358, in get
    clone = self.filter(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/zarathustra/Virtual_Envs/fierce-spring-7383/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 621, in filter
    return self._filter_or_exclude(False, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/zarathustra/Virtual_Envs/fierce-spring-7383/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 639, in _filter_or_exclude
    clone.query.add_q(Q(*args, **kwargs))
  File "/Users/zarathustra/Virtual_Envs/fierce-spring-7383/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py", line 1250, in add_q
    can_reuse=used_aliases, force_having=force_having)
  File "/Users/zarathustra/Virtual_Envs/fierce-spring-7383/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py", line 1114, in add_filter
    opts = self.get_meta()
  File "/Users/zarathustra/Virtual_Envs/fierce-spring-7383/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py", line 233, in get_meta
    return self.model._meta
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '_meta'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a requirement to apply the filter to the User model? Why don't you try to subclass this model instead?, and code a manager for this one.

```
class CustomUserManager(UserManager):

    def get_query_set(self):
        return super(CustomUserManager, self).get_query_set().
          filter(is_active=True)


class MyUser(User):
    objects = CustomUserManager()

# get an active user which username is 'foo'
MyUser.objects.get(username='foo')
```

or use a [proxy model](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#proxy-models)

Comment: This is certainly the better way to do it.  Since we are under a tight deadline, and I didn't want to introduce bugs by changing the model we are using for all of our User related code, I went with a different solution.  But if anyone else is in my boat, I would consider using this instead.

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/531892/django-perform-case-insensitive-lookups-by-default?rq=1).  Since his question is specific and mine is general, I don't consider them duplicates, but the answer to his question also answers mine.