# how to extend/override UserManager

Tags: python, django, django-models

Am on Django 1.6

In my app I'd like to have a User object and a separate profile object. I'd like to avoid implementing a custom User object and instead just use a one-to-one relation to a model that has all the additional fields/info I want.

Whenever I do a query on a User object, 90% of the time I will want to retrieve this profile object. My thinking is that the best way to do this is to modify the get_queryset method of the default UserManager to always retrieve this related object via a "select_related" call.

**Is there a way to do this?**

Searching around this is the only resource i could find on the topic.
[Override Django User Manager to only return active users in queries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14130576/override-django-user-manager-to-only-return-active-users-in-queries)
Do I need to do it this way? Can I instead just somehow use the base User object?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: 90% is still not 100%. Use select_related only when needed, not as default

Answer (score 2):

Since Django 1.5 you can create your [custom user model](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/auth/customizing/#specifying-a-custom-user-model). This eliminates the need of `user_profile`.

Comment: yes i'm aware of this. as it mentions in the docs in the "Model Design Considerations" - "Think carefully before handling information not directly related to authentication in your custom User Model..."  I'm mainly concerned about possibly interferring with other apps. Is this concern unfounded?